# Cross Country/Region DateTime Formating

Tags: c#, datetime, ssis

I am writing a C# script for an ssis package and I am running it on a UK server but I want get a datetime in US format in the form yyyMMdd.

But when I do datevariablename.ToString("yyyyMMdd") it returns a string in the format yyyyddMM.  I even tried by using the Month, Day and Year methods of DateTime but it still gives gives me the day as month and the month as day.

Does anybody know how I can get the string returned in the format yyyyMMdd?  Below is a snippet of my code:

```
private static readonly string[] dateFormat = {  "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                                                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                                                     "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                                                     "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                                                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
                                                     "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                                                     "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                                                     "d/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", "d/M/yyyy hh tt", 
                                                     "d/M/yyyy h:mm", "d/M/yyyy h:mm", 
                                                     "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm"           
                                                  };

    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        var date = DateTime.Now;
        var date2 = DateTime.Now;

        var inputDate = Dts.Variables[dateUnformated].Value;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate.ToString(), dateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            var yyyymmdd = date.Year.ToString() + date.Month.ToString("0#") + date.Day.ToString("0#");

            Dts.Variables[Date1].Value = yyyymmdd;

            Dts.Variables[Date2].Value = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }
```

Comment: use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: Feeding it a mixed list of M/d and d/M formats like that means it will match the first one it finds, which can easily be wrong 12 days of every month

Comment: @Plutonix good point, I still see it being valid as long as the list is ordered in desired precedence.  Because ultimately no one can tell you 1/1/2016 vs 1/1/2016  (MM/dd/yyyy vs dd/MM/yyyy) when the month and day are the same :)

Comment: If there is an existing date - `inputDate` - there is no need to convert it to string and parse it back to a date in order to "change the format".  Doing so  with that hotch potch of formats will at least occasionally change the date.  Given a valid date, `ValidDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` will produce the same result no matter the culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever try this ?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Perfect this worked, the only thing I had to change was I made the date format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss".  The "ddMMyyyy" that you used failed when I ran.  Otherwise it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing using the  [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) Method <kbd>[See the Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oyM8q)</kbd>:

```
string strDate = "09-Aug-2016";
DateTime datDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, new string[]
{
"dd-MMM-yyyy"
}

, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(datDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
}
else
{
    //Error in datetime format
}
```

or even simpler <kbd>[See the Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iV4WWI)</kbd>:

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(datetime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

so there is one more thing to consider.  If you look at a date in SSMS or Excel or .... it will use your computer's culture, because datetime is an object not a string and your computers settings tell intelligent programs how to display it.

so if Date1 variable datatype is date or datetime datatype you are still going to get the wrong format.  You can change Date1 var to string to see what the result is or you can dump your results to text file and open in notepad or something.

First glance seems like @Ozan has a good answer for you on setting the format more efficiently.